# SVD of Frechet derivative

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis

This is mainly a reference request. Is there a particular characterization of operators A from a Hilbert space H to itself such that the Frechet derivative A'(u) exists for each $u \in H$ and for any fixed u, A'(u) has a singular value decomposition.

Comment: What do you mean by "has a singular value decomposition"? There are versions of singular value decomposition that work for all bounded linear operators on a Hilbert space, using polar decomposition and the Spectral Theorem.

Comment: I just mean that $A'(u)^TA'(u)$ has an eigenbasis.